# Is there a way to export a conversation in Ryver?

Tags: ryver

Is there a way to export a conversation in Ryver?  Specifically, I've been direct messaging another member, and since a lot of technical details were given, I'd like to export a transcript of our conversation.

If anyone has used Ryver, have you found such a feature or know an easy way to do this?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 14 times.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a Chrome Extension to address this issue. See it [HERE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chat-downloader-for-ryver/dcebnkfjhcjgjcelndhihklgchhheeke)